# Combine several audio inputs into one

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording

I'd like to use the input from an USB microphone and my sound card (some Realtek)'s Line In input at the same time - so that they could be recorded at the same time by a program *(Audacity or Skype or any program which would normally expect only a single device).*

Is there any solution for that?

I'm on Windows 7, 64-bit.

Comment: If the program supports multiple simultaneous inputs, then it should be able to read from both devices. Have you tried it already? Is there some error or something that’s preventing you?

Comment: No, the program only expects a single recording device to be chosen.